# ¿Como realizar una consulta INNER JOIN mediante query Laravel 6? (htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

estoy empezando a aprender laravel 6 y me gustaria saber como puedo realizar esta consulta.

Intente probando este código en el web.php *(rutas de laravel)*:

```
$as = DB::select("SELECT tipovehis.tipo
                FROM tipovehis
                INNER JOIN vehiculos
                ON vehiculos.tipovehis_id = tipovehis.id
                WHERE vehiculos.tipovehis_id = 3");
return $as;
```

y me devuelve la información esperada. Sin embargo cuando quise probar el mismo codigo para mostrarlo en una tabla de la siguiente forma:

```
<td>
{{
  $as = DB::select("SELECT tipovehis.tipo
          FROM tipovehis
          INNER JOIN vehiculos
          ON vehiculos.tipovehis_id = tipovehis.id
          WHERE vehiculos.tipovehis_id = 3")
}}
</td>
```

Me aparece el siguiente error:

```
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
```

Podria alguien explicarme cual es el error? O es que estoy haciendo mal el inner join?.... Muchas Gracias de ante mano.

***Edit***

Dado que me han mencionado varias veces ya lo de los modelos lo explicare. He estado leyendo la documentacion e investigando pero todos los modelos relacionados que encuentro en hasManyThrough tienen el tipico ejemplo de:

**Countrys 1:N Users 1:N Posts**

y no pude encontrar un ejemplo de relaciones **Countrys 1:N Users N:1 Post** *(entiendo que la relacion anterior no tiene sentido, pero es un ejemplo)* y eso me trae problemas al intentar hacer la consulta desde mi modelo puesto que se como hacer la relacion hasManyThrough de los modelos en el caso:

**Countrys 1:N Users 1:N Posts**

Pero no se como hacer la relacion hasManyThrough en el caso:

**Countrys 1:N Users N:1 Post**

Pensandolo bien hubiese sido una mejor pregunta el edit...

Comment: las consultas en laravel terminan en `->first()` o `->get()` en tu caso solo te falta `$as = DB::select()->get()` aunque te recomiendo usar `Modelos`

Comment: Ya intente agregar el get(), pero me devuelve otro error

Call to a member function get() on array

@manrrique meneses yaranga

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dado que usas laravel no es necesario o incluso bien visto que escribas tus consultas en SQL puro ya que estás desaprovechando todo el potencial de incluir a los modelos en conjunto con las relaciones de Eloquent; dado lo anterior propongo un par de respuestas.

**Opción 1**

Puedes implementar el uso del modelo TipoVehiculo para representar a la tabla `tipovehis` y posteriormente encadenar los métodos necesarios para complementar
tu `JOIN` de esta forma

```
$data = TipoVehiculo::select('tipovehis.tipo')
                  ->join('vehiculos', 'vehiculos.tipovehis_id', '=', 'tipovehis.id')
                  ->where('vehiculos.tipovehis_id', 3)
                  ->get();
```

**Opción 2**

Es nuevamente hacer uso de los modelos, pero esta vez declarar las relaciones que existen en cada uno de ellos.

En el modelo `TipoVehiculo` vas a declarar lo siguiente:

```
class TipoVehiculo extends Model 
{
    public function vehiculos()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Vehiculo::class);
    }
}
```

Posterior ahora en el modelo `Vehiculo` declara la siguiente clase

```
class Vehiculo extends Model 
{
    public function tipoVehiculo()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(TipoVehiculo::class);
    }
}
```

Finalmente en tu controlador puedes construir la siguiente consulta:

```
$data = TipoVehiculo::with(['vehiculos' => function($query){
    $query->where('vehiculos.tipovehis_id', 3);
}])->get();
```

Donde hacemos una carga ambiciosa del modelo con sus respectivas relaciones por medio de eager loading

Comment: acabo de actualizar amigo, si eres tan amable. Gracias

Comment: Respuesta basándome en la consulta mostrada

Comment: Genial, me funciono perfecto la **opcion 1** que propusiste, muchas gracias. Solo una ultima duda. La consulta me devuelve **[{"tipo":"Camion"}]** que es el dato correcto pero lo muestra como un array supongo. Sabrias como puedo mostrar únicamente el dato **"Camion"**. Muchas gracias por la ayuda y perdon por ser tan molestoso jaja @Aprendiz

Comment: Prueba cambiar `get()` por `first()` dado que solo obtienes un valor de regreso, posterior en tu vista trata con: `$data->tipo` eso debería imprimirte el valor que es **camion** en este caso

Comment: Ojala estuvieras cerca para contratarte como mi tutor. Muy util tu ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Si lo intentas de esta forma

```
    $reporte = DB::table("tipovehis as ti")
    ->join('vehiculos as ve', 'ti.id', 've.tipovehis_id ')
    ->select(
        DB::raw("count(ti.tipo) as cantidad"),
        've.tipovehis_id',
        'ti.tipo as tipo'
    )
    ->where("ve.tipovehis_id",3)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Considera checar de nuevo pues no veo que el OP haga un `COUNT` en su consulta